# Youtube IFrame API stopped working

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, youtube-api

I'm trying to use basic onPlayerStateChange events in the Youtube IFrame API to track starts/stops/finishes in Google Analytics. The code worked in October, but now the video won't display. GA tracking code is the same and I get the same results in Wordpress and Drupal. Is it changes to the API?

```
<script> 
var tag = document.createElement('script'); 
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"; 
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player; 
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { 
player = new YT.Player('player', { 
height: '461', 
width: '560', 
videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw', 
events: { 
'onReady': onPlayerReady, 
'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange 
} 
});  
}
function onPlayerReady(event) { 
event.target.playVideo(); 
} 
function onPlayerStateChange(event) { 
if (event.data ==YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) 
{_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', ‘AnyEvent’ ]); } 
if (event.data ==YT.PlayerState.ENDED) 
{_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Watch to End', ‘AnyEvent’]); } } 
</script>

<div id="player"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are curly-single-quotes around ‘AnyEvent’, right? That's not valid JavaScript.